# How to monitor multiple CI/CD pipelines at the same time?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

Is it possible to display multiple CI/CD pipelines at one page? Not how to *run* multiple pipelines but how to *monitor/display* multiple pipelines.

For example let's say we have a monorepo with multiple microservices. I want to see a CI/CD progress for every pipeline currently runs all at one page.

```
auth microservice : lint -> [build] -> test -> deploy
payments microservice: lint -> build -> test -> [deploy]
```

Comment: Do you have multiple or single `.gitlab-ci.yml` file? Can you explain more your project structure? Technically, https://gitlab.com/<username>/<project>/-/pipelines show all currently running pipelines one one page.

Comment: I have a single `.gitlab-ci.yml` file with triggers based on `rules: changes:`. 
Monorepo. 
Basically I want a page like  `gitlab.com/<username>/<project>/-/pipelines/<pipe_id>` but capable of showing multiple pipelines.

Comment: There is no way to achieve this in Gitlab UI.

Comment: If you're using multi-project pipelines, then both the pipelines will be visible in the same page